# constructor value changes unexpectantly c++

Tags: c++, constructor, int, copy-constructor

I have a `Students` class to store `names, ages, gender, subjects, highestmark, lowestmark`.

Basically, I have a `reset()` function which sets everything to `null` and it looks like this

```
char names[10];
char names[10];
char names[10];
int ages;
int highestMark;
int lowestMark;

void Students::reset()
{
  strncpy(names, "NULL", sizeof(names));
  names[9] = '\0';
  ages = 0;
  highestMark = 0;
  lowestMark = 0;
  strncpy(gender, "NULL", sizeof(gender);
  gender[9] = '\0';
  strncpy(subjects, "NULL", sizeof(subjects));
  subjects[9] = '\0';
}
```

My constructor looks like this...

```
Students::Students()
{
  reset();
}
```

Copy constructor looks like this...

```
Students::Students(const Students& student)
{
   reset();
   cout << highestMark << endl; // PRINTS 107894124
   cout << lowestMark << endl;  // PRINTS 541203654
   cout << ages << endl; // PRINTS RANDOM VALUES
   cout << subjects << endl;
   cout << names << endl;
}
```

The `highestMark` and `lowestMark` are not returning `0` and instead returning random values such as `107894124` and `541203654`

Why is it not returning `0` as expected?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it never happened.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Sorry, I have updated the original question

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy(something, NULL)` is undefined behavior, so anything can happen. Most likely you overwrite your data with some junk by calling `strcpy` like that. What you want is probably

```
strcpy(names, "");
```

But it would be much better if you just use `std::string` instead of raw character arrays.

Comment: I have updated my original question. It still does not work, even after trying `strncpy`

Comment: @SamThers passing NULL to `str<whatever>cpy` is UB. I think you are mixing `strncpy` with `memset`.

Comment: I copy `"NULL"` into the arrays using `strncpy` and it still gives me this annoying bug

Comment: @SamThers [I cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea8ec1c4e835257a). Provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you was asked.